# How to get specific request to be Served by Specific application (among multiple running Apps) in a POD in Kubernetes?

Tags: java, docker, asynchronous, kubernetes

I have a Client-Server based application where my clients are available in a Kubernetes as PODs. Here, Clients-Server communication is Asynchronous.

Assume I have five PODs of my client app (POD1, POD2, POD3, POD4, POD5) running in a single Node inside Kubernetes.

Now, I want some specific request to be served by specific running POD inside a Node. This required to be done Asynchronously.

If I send request type1 then it should be handled by POD1 only.
If I send request type2 then it should be handled by POD2 only.

How can I identify whether my request is served by same POD (running instance) or not and How can I achieve it ?

At server side, How can I uniquely identify the POD which has served the request ?

Comment: How are you implementing the asynchrony?  What distinguishes the different message types?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like istio [Here](https://istio.io) which can route traffic to specific pods